# HighCharts : after data update, unable to redraw bars, unless if I click (switch visualization) on the categories for stacked chart, in the legend

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts, stacked-chart

My HighCharts plot is not displaying stacked bars correctly.

Actually, the bar charts are visualized but after an update on the data the plot is blank and gets populated only by a click on the categories that are shown in the legend. This trigger will switch the visualization of that specific stacked bar, causing the plot do be displayed.

How can I display the data immediately, without the aforementioned input from the user?

The following instructions are currently used:

```
this.chart.series[i].setData(data.series[i],true);
```

and:

```
this.chart.xAxis[0].update(data.xAxis,true);
```

As you can see, I added the `redraw=true` additional argument in order to redraw the plot, but it does not work. The plot is initially blank.

**Screenshots of the problem:**
[image: before clicking on a category]

After clicking on the "screenview" category you can see the result:
[image: after clicking on a category]

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having some bizarre issues with highcharts failing to redraw after an empty series is added to a chart.

Comment: cannot solve it. Might be a bug.